# Download files in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I wanted to download a file in flask application, i have below code which downloads into downloads directory, but when it is deployed in a different environment, it fails as the operating system is different.

```
folder = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads")
df.to_csv(folder + '/Data.csv', index=False)
```

I tried using flask response as well, code is being executed but file is not getting dowloaded,

```
return Response(
        df,
        mimetype="text/csv",
        headers={"Content-disposition":
                     "attachment; filename=Data.csv"})
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Could you clarify more, Are you trying to download a folder from some internet URL to the server running flask ? ( if yes this question should not have the flask tag since it has nothing to do with flask ). Or maybe you mean the user uploaded a file from his browser to your flask server and you want to save it ( download it ) to the server running flask ?